# Forge Viewer Markups latest version

Tags: autodesk-forge, viewer, markup-extensions

I created Forge viewer version 7 in my own website. I'm trying to add markups like the one shown in Autodesk website (see picture below);

[image: markup example]

Are there any tutorial for creating markups tool like this? I found some but they are either outdated version or incomplete. Please suggest, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach would be to use the built-in `MarkupsGui` extension which provides UI to create markups:

```
NOP_VIEWER.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui")
//or turn on the extension during initialization
new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container,{extensions:['Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui']})
```

Then a button will appear in the toolbar to trigger the extension:

[image]

Alternatively you can come up with your own UI and leverage the `MarkupsCore` extension which is also built-in to programmatically switch between markup tools and even create markups programmatically, see documentation [here](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/tutorial-feature_markup.html)

You can either call or extend these to create your own custom extension.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very helpful. May I ask about the next step to store the modified data with markups? Where to store and how to store? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can look that up around and find similar answers say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=forge+markup+restore)